# Rand() case switch runs to infinity after multiple iterations

Tags: c++

I am writing a simple c++ script to randomly assign people in a gift exchange. Yes I know other codes or even excel is probably better for this, but this is more of an exercise in my c++ skills than anything.

Anyway, here is an example of how I am generating a random pick:

```
jakegen:
  jake = rand() % 5;
  if (jake == tommy || jake == kendra) {
    goto jakegen;
  }
  switch (jake) {
    case 0: std::cout << "Jake has: Tommy \n";
      break;
    case 1: std::cout << "Jake has: Kendra \n";
      break;
    case 2: goto jakegen;
      break;
    case 3: goto jakegen;
      break;
    case 4: std::cout << "Jake has: Abby \n";
      break;
  }
```

So I generate a random number within my range (0-4), check if it duplicates a previous pick and re-roll if it does, and then the first roll that doesn't match a previous pick goes into a switch to see who the pick is.

I also added the ability to re-roll at the end by going back to the start (after initializing variables, before rolling any random numbers).

My problem is that, if I re-roll a few times, the last person in the pick process will never settle on a number. It will loop between rolling a number, checking it, and re-rolling on into infinity.

I have no idea why this is happening, there should always be one available number by the end. Any obvious problems? I can post the rest of the code if asked for.

Comment: Note: The [modern random facilities](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) are *far* superior to `srand()`/`rand()`.

Comment: it is always more efficient to roll a number in only the range of allowed values rather than rolling a number until it falls within the range of allowed values, in your example, your random number has a range of 5 different values, but only for 3 you do not continue to reroll. Better pick a random number out of 3 from the start

Comment: You can replace the `goto` with a function. Something that loops forever and returns if case 0, 1, or 4 is reached. In general though, put all of the names in a library container, `std::vector` probably, then [apply `std::shuffle`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle). Pick the entries in pairs. The first two are a pair, the second two are a pair...

Answer (score 0):

In this code snippet

```
jakegen:
  jake = rand() % 5;
  if (jake == tommy || jake == kendra) {
    goto jakegen;
  }
  switch (jake) {
    case 0: std::cout << "Jake has: Tommy \n";
      break;
    case 1: std::cout << "Jake has: Kendra \n";
      break;
    case 2: goto jakegen;
      break;
    case 3: goto jakegen;
      break;
    case 4: std::cout << "Jake has: Abby \n";
      break;
  }
```

if jake == tommy or jake == kendra the control is passed to the label `jakegen`.

So it seems the control never is passed to these labels

```
case 0: std::cout << "Jake has: Tommy \n";
  break;
case 1: std::cout << "Jake has: Kendra \n";
  break;
```

In any other case except when jake is equal to 4 the control is also passed to the label `jakegen`.

```
    case 2: goto jakegen;
      break;
    case 3: goto jakegen;
      break;
```

And in the presented code snippet it is unclear when the variables `tommy` or `kendra` are assigned.